# couchbase query result value always returns null

Tags: javascript, couchbase

```
var query = mycouchbase.view('doc', 'myview');


query.query({
    limit: 1 
}, function(err, results) {

    for (i in results) console.log(results[i]);

});
```

in couchbase admin console what I saw is

[image]

but in javascript console

```
console - { id: '1NR10', key: '1NR10', value: null }
```

value always is null

your comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by default "IncludeDocs" is false, so you will need to explicitly set IncludeDocs: true (please check exacte syntax in the [documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.0/#finding-data-with-views))

Comment: thanks, I try but same result: value is null in javascript console